# Using for loop to create a new matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would need some help to create a matrix from different arrays using loop(This is the best option right?)

Firstly, I have a array with different distances to a beach called durres(the distances are in kilometers), here is my array code:

```
KM_to_Durres = [13.7; 13.3; 12.7; 11.3; 7.4; 6.1; 8.7; 14.4; 16.4; 21.2; 23.4; 21.3; 18.5; 17.1; 22.2;]
```

The next array is different maximum range that you could drive by a different EV(tesla, nissan leaf etc etc): Here is my array code for that:

```
Ranges_By_Different_EV = [199; 250; 300; 557; 190; 300; 250; 160; 403; 280; 200; 489;]
```

The next 4 vectors here show how much range range in KM i have left with a battery status of 90,80,70 and 60.

code:

```
How_Much_Range_left_With_90battery = 90* (Ranges_By_Different_EV/100)

How_Much_Range_left_With_80battery = 80* (Ranges_By_Different_EV/100)


How_Much_Range_left_With_70battery = 70* (Ranges_By_Different_EV/100)


How_Much_Range_left_With_60battery = 60* (Ranges_By_Different_EV/100)
```

This will create 4 arrays that shows how much the different EV`s can drive with the battery statuses of 90,80,70,60.

What I want now is to loop through this so I also can create a average use matrix!

The formula is "AverageUse = Current_Battery_status / distance
Example: If I ahve 60% left after I drived 13.7km(the first element of the "KM_to_Durrest" vector, then I get an average use of 4.379.

So how can I create a new array/matrix based on these vector I already have?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what is it that you actually want to do? Calculate how far you will get depending on the current battery level? Do you aim to plot a diagram with x-axis 'battery level' and y-axis 'how many KM left'? What's the reasoning behind using the vectors you provide?

Comment: Never create multiple named variables (`How_Much_Range_left_With_90battery` etc.) in Matlab.  If you want to loop over battery levels (`60:10:90`), do that. Store the resulting data in a larger array, cell array, struct, etc. depending on needs.

Comment: It is for a small project. And yes! I forgot to mention, if also could plot diagrams, that would be good :)
Could you provide an code example?

Comment: No tips available??